# How should I create bi-directional communication with named pipes?

Tags: c#, .net, ipc, named-pipes

There are a bunch of different solutions here, I’m guessing many using older versions of .NET and/or Windows.

What’s the latest recommended way to set up named pipes for bi-directional communication.

We’re on .NET 4.5.1.

And I have multiple instances of my app, all on the same machine. So first instance will try to start as the client, fail, and then be the server.

Thanks dave

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you want named pipes over other IPC solutions?

Comment: @TheGeneral - just that it's generally my go-to solution. I do think using UDP is heavy handed for IPC where all are running on the same machine under the same credentials.